# Why does jquery prev() works fine but next() fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="general_images">
  <a href="href_1" data-id="id_1">
    <img src="some_source">
  </a>
  <a href="href_2" data-id="id_2">
    <img src="some_source">
  </a>
  <a href="href_3" data-id="id_3">
    <img src="some_source">
  </a>
  <a href="href_4" data-id="id_4">
    <img src="some_source">
  </a>
  <a href="href_5" data-id="id_5">
    <img src="some_source">
  </a>
</div>
```

& I have used following js code to get the values of next and previous fields:

```
$(".general_images a").click(function(e){
  data_prev = $(this).prev().attr('data-id');
  data_next = $(this).next().attr('data-id');
});
```

However for some reason `.prev().attr('data-id')` is retruning correct value whereas `.next().attr('data-id')` returns undefined.

Any ingsights or suggestions?

Comment: Works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/CyDhK/

Comment: `data_id` or `data-id`?

Comment: `var e = document.querySelectorAll('.general_images a'); for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) e[i].onclick = function() { console.log(this.previousSibling.dataset.id, this.nextSibling.dataset.id) }`

Comment: side note - you can do .data('id') instead of attr('data-id')

Comment: the `next()` element will be undefined when you click the last (5th) element, and the `prev()` element will be undefined when you click the first element, because nothing comes before first or after next, its not circular

Comment: @KaiQing - Only IE11 supports customer data attributes expanding to `dataset`, if IE support is needed.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I thought jQuery handles the support issue for us? `.data` is a standard method in jQuery, it should be used in this case.

Comment: @KingKing - There's a difference between `.dataset` and `jQuery.data()`. `.dataset()`, which auto-expands `data-` custom attributes, relies on browser support, and jQuery does not add that support. Probably because it would be dreadfully terribly slow to do so. Hence, `jQuery.data()` for `data-` attributes requires browser support, although you can use `jQuery.data()` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works just fine. The issue you are having is simple:

next() and prev() get elements within the same "level" on the elements tree. When you click on the first image that has the `data-id="id_1"` attribute, you can see that there is no element that comes before that one, that's why it's giving you `"undefined"`.

The same thing will happen on next() if you click on the image within the `data-id="id_5"` attribute, you can see that there is no element that comes after that one.